# open vpn connection error after traveling to another country

Tags: network-manager, openvpn

I have been trying to connect to an open VPN server that was working fine before until I traveled to another country last week and now the VPN isn't connecting
VPN logs:

```
Sep 15 12:38:38 fawrama nm-openvpn[113480]: library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022, LZO 2.10
Sep 15 12:38:38 fawrama nm-openvpn[113480]: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Sep 15 12:38:38 fawrama nm-openvpn[113480]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Sep 15 12:38:38 fawrama nm-openvpn[113480]: TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]60.54.119.66:9992
Sep 15 12:38:38 fawrama nm-openvpn[113480]: UDP link local: (not bound)
Sep 15 12:38:38 fawrama nm-openvpn[113480]: UDP link remote: [AF_INET]IPaddress
Sep 15 12:38:38 fawrama nm-openvpn[113480]: NOTE: chroot will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Sep 15 12:38:38 fawrama nm-openvpn[113480]: NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Sep 15 12:39:38 fawrama nm-openvpn[113480]: TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Sep 15 12:39:38 fawrama nm-openvpn[113480]: TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Sep 15 12:39:38 fawrama nm-openvpn[113480]: SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Sep 15 12:39:38 fawrama NetworkManager[845]: <warn>  [1694752778.6482] vpn[0x562f854a06e0,92a0139f-933a-404f-8b80-e8b562ca2625,"KollectSystemsVPN"]: connect timeout exceeded
Sep 15 12:39:38 fawrama nm-openvpn-serv[113475]: Connect timer expired, disconnecting.
Sep 15 12:39:38 fawrama nm-openvpn[113480]: SIGTERM[hard,init_instance] received, process exiting
```

Comment: The country you're in may be trying a "Man-In-The-Middle" attack. Do what the error message suggests, see http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm

Comment: Can you ping the IP address you are trying to connect to? `TLS Error:` usually means you cannot connect to the IP Address or port.